# How to share data between two elements in Polymer 2.0

Tags: data-binding, polymer

I have the following elements, which simply has an attribute, which the element itself sets:

```
<link rel="import" href="../polymer/polymer-element.html">

<dom-module id="test-element-1">
  <template>
    <style>
      :host {
        display: block;
      }
    </style>
    <h2>Hello [[prop1]]!</h2>
  </template>

  <script>
    /**
     * `test-element-1`
     * Test Element 1
     *
     * @customElement
     * @polymer
     * @demo demo/index.html
     */
    class TestElement1 extends Polymer.Element {
      static get is() { return 'test-element-1'; }
      static get properties() {
        return {
          prop1: {
            type: String,
            value: 'test-element-1',
            notify: true,
            readOnly: true
          }
        };
      }
    }

    window.customElements.define(TestElement1.is, TestElement1);
  </script>
</dom-module>
```

and I'd like a second element to be able to use the same data:

```
<link rel="import" href="../polymer/polymer-element.html">

<dom-module id="test-element-2">
  <template>
    <style>
      :host {
        display: block;
      }
    </style>
    <h2>Hello [[prop1]]!</h2>
  </template>

  <script>
    /**
     * `test-element-2`
     * Test Element 2
     *
     * @customElement
     * @polymer
     * @demo demo/index.html
     */
    class TestElement2 extends Polymer.Element {
      static get is() { return 'test-element-2'; }
      static get properties() {
        return {
          prop1: {
            type: String,
            notify: false,
            readOnly: false
          }
        };
      }
    }

    window.customElements.define(TestElement2.is, TestElement2);
  </script>
</dom-module>
```

I'd like Test Element 2 to be able to get the value of prop1 from Test Element 1:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, minimum-scale=1, initial-scale=1, user-scalable=yes">

    <title>test-element-2 demo</title>

    <script src="../../webcomponentsjs/webcomponents-lite.js"></script>

    <link rel="import" href="../../iron-demo-helpers/demo-pages-shared-styles.html">
    <link rel="import" href="../../iron-demo-helpers/demo-snippet.html">
    <link rel="import" href="../test-element-2.html">
    <link rel="import" href="../../test-element-1/test-element-1.html">

    <custom-style>
      <style is="custom-style" include="demo-pages-shared-styles">
      </style>
    </custom-style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="vertical-section-container centered">
      <h3>Basic test-element-2 demo</h3>
      <demo-snippet>
        <template>
          <test-element-1 prop1="{{prop1Value}}"></test-element-1>
          <test-element-2 prop1="{{prop1Value}}"></test-element-2>
        </template>
      </demo-snippet>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Here's the output of my demo though:
[image]

What is it that I'm doing wrong?

Comment: you could create a new component, let's say test-elements-wrapper, to include both of them and keep the value in sync, and in your page you would include that wrapper, not the two individual elements

Answer (score 1):

Since you are using `index.html` or any other HTML page to display the value of polymer elements, it cannot bind the value of `prop1Value`.

If you do same thing using a `polymer-element` then it will definitely work.

> A property is declared implicitly if you add it to a data binding or
>   add it as a dependency of an observer, computed property, or computed
>   binding.
>
> Polymer automatically creates setters for these implicitly declared
>   properties. However, implicitly declared properties can't be
>   configured from markup.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is explained by @Osifara, if  you want share property with children components you need to make the top level parent a webcomponent,
you need to do something like this:

```
<body>
    ......the other code

    <dom-module id="my-index">
        <template>
            <demo-snippet>
                <template>
                    <test-element-1 prop1="{{propIndexTest}}"></test-element-1>
                    <test-element-2 prop1="{{propIndexTest}}"></test-element-2>
                </template>
            </demo-snippet>
        </template>
    </dom-module>
    <my-index></my-index>
    ......the other code
</body>
<script>
    class MyIndex extends Polymer.Element {
        static get is() {
            return 'my-index';
        }
        static get properties() {
            return {
                propIndexTest: {
                    type: String,
                    value: 'We are sharing the same value'
                    notify: false
                }
            };
        }
    }

    window.customElements.define(MyIndex.is, MyIndex);
</script>
```

So now  becames your top level parent container and then you can use the Polymer to work with that.